# split string by ' ' and &nbsp; using regex

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
var myTXT = "Aa bbb&nbsp;cccc" ;
```

How can I split it by **white space** (' ') and **& nbsp;** using a regex

The expected output is

```
Aa at index 0
bbb at index 1
cccc at index 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [or](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cs%7C%26nbsp%3B%2Fg)

```js
console.log("Aa bbb&nbsp;cccc".split(/\s|&nbsp;/g))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it works but I've wanted to expend the test with break line supposing that the string is `Aa <br>bbb&nbsp;<br>cccc`  so I did `"Aa <br>bbb&nbsp;<br>cccc".split(/\s|&nbsp;|<br>/g)` but the br was displayed as white space

Comment: because you have a space and a br beside each other and the reg exp is not expecting that.

Comment: so there is no solution in this case ? ps the white space is just beside the first <br> and not for the second –

Comment: `"Aa <br>bbb&nbsp;<br>cccc".split(/(?:<br\s*\/?>|\s|&nbsp;)+/gi)`

Comment: could you please explain that regex ! for example what does `?` do and why `<br\s*\/?>` is written like that (if I understand it I can use in other contexts)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: [regexper](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%3F%3A%3Cbr%5Cs*%5C%2F%3F%3E%7C%5Cs%7C%26nbsp%3B%29%2B%2Fgi)